# Reversible thermodynamics processes

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

A problem asks me to find the entropy increment in the machine operating some thermodynamic cycle. Can I assume that any closed cycle can (theoretically) be obtained by using two reservoirs at some temperatures and computing the entropy increment in each?

Comment: You need to give more information about the process. It could involve any number of reservoirs and other equipment (Pumps? turbines? ...)

Answer (score 0):

No.  The equipment required to carry out a specified cycle reversibly will depend on the complexity of the cycle. You may need an array of reservoirs, a set of weights ranging over many sizes, and an array of semi-permeable membranes.